# updating and retrieving just one row in a table ms sql java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sql-server, jdbc

I have a scenario where I want to just update one row always,,The row has just one column and I also want to retrieve that single row always..The query I am using to insert is this :

```
stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO esp_salamstate " + 
             "VALUES ('on') ");
```

But every time this runs it adds another row.

While the query I am using to get the values is this :

```
final String GET_POSSIBLE_BINS = "SELECT state,id FROM esp_salamstate";
```

please help ...thanks in advance...

Comment: If you insert, you add. If you update, you change.

Comment: You need some way to be able to identify the row and then you want o use the `update` function. `update esp_salamstate set on=?` or some such...

Comment: Should I add another column of id for identification ? @MadProgrammer Would You please tell me the proper query for that If I add the id column ?If you don't mind.

Comment: It would make life easier, if you know the id for the row you can use something like `update esp_salamstate set on=? where id=?`, this will allow you to modify a single row, based on the id column value

Comment: and how to retrieve the value where id is 1 ? @MadProgrammer

Comment: `select * from esp_salamstate where id = ?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a single column and a single row, then all you need to do is:

```
UPDATE esp_salamstate SET state='on'
```

Without a `WHERE` clause, this updates all rows (which we assume "are" always just one row) to whatever value you set.